# Am I straining my graphics card? (nvlddmkm stopped then recovered)

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I am now on my second [NVIDIA GeForce GT710](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt-710/specifications) graphics card in my 18 month old PC which I use to drive three monitors. With the first card I had, about once a day the screen would turn black for about a second and then recover. If I looked at the windows logs I could see a warning:

```
Display driver nvlddmkm stopped responding and has successfully recovered.
```

After a few months one of the three outputs stopped working altogether, so I got a new GT710. I uninstalled the old driver and then rebooted so that windows would install a new driver itself. The current driver is version 23.21.13.8813. Now after a few days I have just seen exactly the same black-screen and warning message.

The GPU is running at 58 degrees C and is registering 0.875Volts (according to [CPUID HW Monitor](https://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html)).

My three monitors have resolutions of 2560x1600, 1920x1200 and 1680x1050.

This PC is used for business only, running databases, compilers and 2D graphics. It usually runs 24/7 with the monitors turned off at night. I don't play any games on it.

My motherboard is an ASUS x99-A with a "Corsair 450W VS series" power supply, an [i7-6850K CPU](https://ark.intel.com/de/products/94188/Intel-Core-i7-6850K-Processor-15M-Cache-up-to-3_80-GHz) a CoolerMaster Hyper 212X fan, 32GB of RAM (HyperX SAVAGE DDR4 3000MHz) and a 1TB SSD (Samsung 850 EVO). My windows version is 1709, build 16299.64.

Any idea how I can prevent this glitch?

Comment: What version of the Nvidia driver are you using.  Please edit your question and include the information within the body of your question.  Update your question to refer to the specific build of Windows 10 you are using.  If you are using an Insider Preview build please indicate that fact.

Comment: Question edited as requested.

Comment: Your GPU is more then capable of handling your usage case.  You have software that is causing a fault, and it appears Windows is recovering from, but your statements don't support that conclusion to it's entirety. .

Comment: @Ramhound: When you say "You have software that is causing a fault," - do you mean the driver? or some other software? Some of the programs that are running are my own. Could a bug of mine be the cause?

Comment: 58 degree Celsius is nowhere near stressing the card thermally, so the problem is likely somewhere else.

Comment: @Mick - I mean exactly what I said.  You have software that is performing a hardware function, being handled by the GPU, which causes a fault and then Windows attempts and is able to successfully recover the display driver which handles displaying your desktop.  What software that is, on your system, I couldn't tell you.

Comment: What PSU are you using, how old is it, and how does it compare to how much power you are trying to pull from it?  A failing/old/underpowered PSU could account for this, where the GPU is trying to turn off outputs to try to use less power, due to it having fewer amps or volts than it needs.  IDK this for sure, but it's something to check/consider.

Comment: @Computercarguy: I have edited in more details about my hardware to the original question. With regard "how much power you are trying to pull from it" - I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the max CPU and GPU power requirements (140W and 300W respectively), I'm going to have to suggest that your power supply isn't up to the task.

Compilers and graphics (even 2D) are known to be CPU intensive.  Even databases can be resource hogs, depending on their use.

With the specs you list, I'm guessing you're using 16-32gb RAM, maybe multiple hard drives (and/or SSDs), and several fans, so I'm going to suggest you get rid of the $45 PSU and buy a +800 watt PSU.  Getting one that's rated 80Plus Bronze or better will help keep your power consumption down and should give you better components, so it'll last longer under your load.

This may also fix any other "odd" issues you may have been seeing and simply not told us about in this post.

Comment: If you look at the specs for the graphics card the OP linked to, it says "Graphics Card Power (W) 19." Far less that the 140 W you suggest. And the CPU has a maximum TDP of 140 W. I think maybe you saw the last line of the GPU card specs which says the minimum recommended system PSU is 300 W and transposed the figures.

Comment: Yep, I should have proofread it before posting.  Running 3 monitors at the resolution the OP is, I'd be really surprised if it's only pulling 19W, but that's what the specs say, so who am I to argue.  Based on the other hardware that's probably in the machine, though, I still think a 450w PSU is too small.  I don't put anything less than a 600w in a basic desktop, unless it's an ITX or smaller system.